# can I use router to share internet if ISP sometimes requires web auth

Tags: networking, router

My ISP allows me to connect only using ethernet (ethernet socket just in the wall, because the same ISP provides internet for the whole building [student halls]) and sometimes requires web auth after connecting. It redirects to their homepage where I have to enter login/pwd (couldn't find how this is called).

I want to use two laptops and it sucks to keep connecting and disconnecting the only available cable.

I was thinking about getting a switch but I guess it won't work because it will need one IP for each laptop allocated by ISP (but I guess they allocate one-per-apartment (socket) so won't work). At least according to my understanding.

What about getting a router? From what I understood back in network classes, router would get one IP and my two laptops would act as a subnet. Which is fine. But what about that web auth thing?

Thanks!

Comment: Its unlike the terms of your ISP allows for something like this. I know when I was living in a college dorm the use of a router was a great way to be banned from the network for the entire semester.

Comment: I agree with @Ramhound. The reason they require web authentication is to keep people from doing what you are asking about. You may want to read your housing agreement or network policy before you get yourself in trouble.